# How not to expose port outside docker swarm cluster?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

Hello how can I define in compose port only for communication inside cluster? I don't want to expose my application outside cluster?

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  management:
    image: ${IMAGE}
    env_file:
      - vars.env
    networks:
      - my-network
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
      replicas: 1
      update_config:
        parallelism: 2
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure

networks:
  my-network:
    external: true
```

```
ports:
  - 8080:80
```

Will expose my app outside swarm cluster. Ho can I make my app accessible only inside cluster via port 80?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just omit the port from the `ports` section that you do not wish to expose outside the ingress network. Example nginx.yaml:

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  nginx-1:
    image: nginx:alpine 
  nginx-2:
    image: nginx:alpine
```

`docker stack deploy -c nginx.yaml nginx`

`docker stack ps nginx`

`docker exec -t <nginx-1 container ID> wget -qO- nginx-2`

The command will print the response from nginx-2 to nginx-1 accordingly. It is not mandatory to list the port under `ports` section in order to access a container port **within** the Swarm network.

For your case it means your sample spec do not need the `ports` section since you do not wish to expose 80 outside the Swarm network.

Comment: But how can I access my service inside cluster in that case? If I will not define even target/container port?

Comment: Checkout the updated answer with a working sample.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation!